# How can one list out all the payment_id's that has received funds?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, address, integrated-address

Is there a way in `monero-cli` to find out all the previously used payment `id` that has received funds?

Basically I just want a list of every transaction that has a payment id associated with it. I want to see the date, amount, and payment id.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to show old payment IDs. In the future you can however make use of subaddresses: https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/2056

Comment: It's really unclear what youre asking. Try rephrasing.

Comment: ok rewrote it a bit better.